# Not able to install new wxpython

Tags: python, gstreamer, wxpython

I am working on Debian Stable Linux and python 3.5 and I am trying to install the new wxpython (phoenix) using following command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade wxpython
```

However, it stops with following error:

```
  checking for CAIRO... yes
    checking for cairo_push_group... yes
    checking for GST... configure: WARNING: GStreamer 1.0 not available, falling back to 0.10
    checking for GST... configure: WARNING: GStreamer 0.10 not available, falling back to 0.8
    configure: error: GStreamer not available
    Error running configure
    ERROR: failed building wxWidgets
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "build.py", line 1269, in cmd_build_wx
        wxbuild.main(wxDir(), build_options)
      File "/tmp/pip-build-pdn9eo0c/wxpython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 376, in main
        "Error running configure")
      File "/tmp/pip-build-pdn9eo0c/wxpython/buildtools/build_wxwidgets.py", line 85, in exitIfError
        raise builder.BuildError(msg)
    buildtools.builder.BuildError: Error running configure
    Finished command: build_wx (0m9.685s)
    Finished command: build (0m9.686s)
    Command '"/usr/bin/python3" -u build.py build' failed with exit code 1.
```

I have following packages related to gstreamer installed:

```
Package                 Installed       Previous        Now             State
=======================-===============-===============-===============-=====
gir1.2-gst-plugins-base-1.0 1.10.4-1        1.10.4-1        1.10.4-1        install
gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0    1.10.4-1        1.10.4-1        1.10.4-1        install
libgstreamer1.0-dev     1.10.4-1        1.10.4-1        1.10.4-1        install
libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer   1:5.2.7-1       1:5.2.7-1       1:5.2.7-1       install
python3-gst-1.0         1.10.4-1        1.10.4-1        1.10.4-1        install
```

What other gstreamer package do I need to install? Thanks for your help.

Comment: probably libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-0 and maybe libgstreamer1.0-0

Comment: See also: https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/,
https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/index.html,
https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/blob/master/README.rst

Comment: Yes, the build started working but it was taking a long time and took up more than 1 Gb of disk space, so I had to give up.

Comment: For Debian 9 using Python 3.5+ and GTK3.x+ try using the prebuilt wheel from the extras.wxpython.org site: ```pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/debian-9/wxPython-4.0.1-cp35-cp35m-linux_x86_64.whl wxPython```

Comment: Is there a prebuilt for 32 bit Debian-9 system, because that is what I have (Linux debian 4.9.0-3-686-pae) ?

Answer (score 10):

I find that the only way to install wxPython on Ubuntu 16.04 is by executing this command:

```
sudo pip install -U -f https://extras.wxpython.org/wxPython4/extras/linux/gtk3/ubuntu-16.04     wxPython
```

if you just execute the usual

```
sudo pip install wxPython
```

then it will fail complaining about GStreamer missing (but I have all the required packages installed, of course).

Comment: The explanation why you can't just do 'pip install wxPython' on Linux: https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip/index.html  Above, Tigran is doing the equivalent of installing wxPython using a specific .whl file built for Ubuntu16.04. If you visit the extra.wxpython.org site you can find prebuilt wheel files for a few different Linux flavours, however as it stands as of this comment there is no easy 'pip install wxPython' for Linux like there is for Windows/OS X (because of the reasons mentioned in the first link I gave).

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://wxpython.org/pages/downloads/index.html) and above, pip isn't going to help you (unless you build yourself the thing directly [from sources](https://wiki.wxpython.org/How%20to%20install%20wxPython#Installing_wxPython_from_source) that is).

And while there *are* plenty of binaries already available, the joke is that those provided by the OS are just for python 2.7, while those provided by the official development team are not for i386.

Thankfully one of the wx developers I think, had the courtesy to [set up a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~swt-techie/+archive/ubuntu/wxpython4) during testing.. And I believe there shouldn't be any [special](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/448230/how-can-i-add-a-ppa-with-only-ubuntu-releases-to-a-debian-machine) incompatibility between Xenial and Stretch, considering they share the same python3 version eventually (there's even [a newer one](https://launchpad.net/~delmic-soft/+archive/ubuntu/odemis/+packages) but it bumps the sip-py3api-11.2 dependency that may be hard required by some other package)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:swt-techie/wxpython4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-wxgtk4.0
```